# Socket uses random ports and I need a certain one

Tags: python, sockets

Here is the problem, I want to create a connection between two computer in two networks in a certain port but when I am running the run I got this message that shows me every single time different ports:

```
Accepted a connection request from 192.168.1.2:**12345**
DATA
```

**This is the listening code:**

```
import socket
import logging 


serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

serverSocket.bind(("**server's Local ip**",6464))

serverSocket.listen(1)

while(True):
    
    (clientConnected, clientAddress) = serverSocket.accept()
    print("Accepted a connection request from %s:%s"%(clientAddress[0], clientAddress[1])) #[0], ...[1]
    dataFromClient = clientConnected.recv(1024)
    print(dataFromClient.decode())

    clientConnected.send("Hello User".encode())
    user = dataFromClient
    cip = clientAddress
    LOG_FILENAME = '/home/user/listenlog.txt'
    logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,level=logging.DEBUG)
    logging.debug(cip)
    logging.debug(user)
    logging.debug("--------------------------------------------------------")
```

**and this is the client code:**

```
import socket

clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

clientSocket.connect(("**Server's IP**",6464))


data = 'Hello'


clientSocket.send(data.encode())

dataFromServer = clientSocket.recv(1024)

print(dataFromServer.decode())
```

How should I make the using port static?

Comment: What makes you think that's necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the connection that you got is public and behind nat
it is usual to be a random port because it is from isp or nat device so else i dont think that would be local

Comment: Yeah i was reading "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3027" today and i saw that, thank you for the answer and you are right.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your client’s socket to be bound to a specific port, you can call bind() on the socket before you call connect() on it.

Note that there is typically no benefit to doing that, however.  The downside is that if that port is already in use, the bind() call will fail.